# Sense shortcut icon reverts to standard Android icon after reboot

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, htc-sense, home-screen-shortcuts

I have recently purchased an HTC Sensation, and I'm very happy with the device; everything runs smooth and fast as I should expect from the device itself.

When rebooting the device, I tend to lose a lot of shortcut icons on the Sense screens; they revert back to some default Android icon. This causes me to remove the icons that were "defaulted" and put them on there again to get the correct icons.
Being new to the Android community, I was wondering if anyone knows why this is happening.

The device is an HTC Sensation running Android 2.3.3 and HTC Sense 3.0.

Comment: Are the icons that get defaulted shortcuts to things on the phone's SD card?  And if you leave them alone after a reboot, do they come back after a while?  It might just be that the SD card is busy being scanned immediately following a reboot, so the OS seems to put off loading inconsequential things like icons for a few minutes.

Comment: @Matt Exactly. I have an HTC Desire and it does behave in this way, for applications that have been installed on the SD card. It usually takes 30 seconds up to a minute until the SD card is ready, and they reappear back.

Comment: For me on HTC Sensation icons stay at default android scheme, apps on phone are fine they have proper icons.

Comment: as mentioned before, it happens when the app is installed/moved onto the SD Card. Even after waiting it still doesn't get the normal icon ... so I guess bug?

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty way to reload your icons in HTC sense UI!
Change scene to anything else, then change scene back!
Temporary fix till next boot or smth but that's the only way i know how to do it right now.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug that HTC have not addressed yet, it is not the same as the 2.2 model phones, and seems to only happen on this the latest versions of gingerbread.
Its not like the old thing where the executable has been moved to the SD card, as I haven't moved anything and I still get it on some apps. It doesn't jsut go away, it is permamnet when it happens and the only atm to fix is to either reload your UI, or dump the desktop icons and replace them.

C'mon HTC!! Sort it out

Answer (score 0):

I get this after reboot on CM6 for applications moved to SD card. The problem fixes itself after a little time. I'd blame a slow SD card, if you're not running Sense.